# How to setState when login error occurs

Tags: reactjs

If my application returns an error because a user incorrectly logs in (eg. email doesn't exist) I get an error in console `Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the LoginForm component.`. From what I can tell it's to do with the application trying to move from a public to authenticated route and then back again. I can't figure out how I'm supposed to mount the state of `loginError` so that this error doesn't appear.

Login: `where login fails and state is set`

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    loginError: ''
  };

  this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      this.setState({ loginError: error.reason });
    }
  });
}
```

Error:  `It appears the error is occurring here`

```
const Public = ({ loggingIn, authenticated, component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={(props) => {
      if (loggingIn) return <div />;
      return !authenticated ?
      (React.createElement(component, { ...props, loggingIn, authenticated })) :
      (<Redirect to="/" />);
    }}
  />
);
```

Comment: The problem could be with `Meteor.loginWithPassword` It should not set authenticated to true if there is an error.

Comment: I think the page reloads so the component isn't considered loaded. How do you deal with that?

Comment: send the login error as props to the component and handle the login in a parent component